# Field typing limite by cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Here I have made validation if anybody type more than 6 digits after submit he will get message 'Not more than 6 digits!!'.But in here I want to make a another validation that is,before send data user will be enable to type more than six character in field.How can I solve it ?

Here my model code

```
public $validate = array(
        'name' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Name is required and cannot be empty!!!',
                'required' => true,
        ),
        'ssc_roll' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'S.S.C Roll is required and cannot be empty!!!',
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 6),
                'message' => 'Not more than 6 digits!!',
                'required' => true,
        ),
        'hsc_roll' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'H.S.C Roll is required and cannot be empty!!!',
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 6),
                'message' => 'Not more than 6 digits!!',
                'required' => true,
        ),
        'date_of_birth' => array(
                'rule' => array('date'),
                'message' => 'Enter a valid date.',
                'required' => true,
        ),
        'mobile' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                'message' => 'Enter a valid mobile number.',
                'required' => true,
        )

);
```

and here the view code

```
<div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="name">S.S.C Roll *</label>
<div class="controls">
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input('ssc_roll', array('class'=>'input-large'));
echo $this->Form->error('ssc_roll'); ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="name">H.S.C Roll *</label>
<div class="controls">
<?php echo $this->Form->input('hsc_roll', array('class'=>'input-large'));
echo $this->Form->error('hsc_roll'); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the 6 digits validation in the given code ? Anyway, if you settled a validation 'digits < 7' and you want your users to be able to write more, simply remove the validation ?

Comment: I have just edited my code.Here the validation code.Here I want user will be enable to type more than 6 digits in input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to validate another field with a new number of digits allowed, change the MaxLength rule to match to maximum number of digits allowed :

```
    // 4 digits instead of 6
    'zip_code' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Zip code is required and cannot be empty!!!',
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 4), 
            'message' => 'Not more than 4 digits!!',
            'required' => true,
    ),
    // 10 digits instead of 6
    'phone_number' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Phone number is required and cannot be empty!!!',
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 10),
            'message' => 'Not more than 10 digits!!', 
            'required' => true,
    ),
```

Comment: Here no any problem with validation because I want the validation.I want another validation in input field like as zip code.If you want to type zip code in field.You can't type more than 4 digits.

Comment: Edited my answer, the validation comes from the maxLength property, just modify it to whatever you want. Anyway, just check CakePhP reference about these controls to know which properties you can tweak to get the validation you want, it will be quicker than asking everytime you need a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your validation on the fly based on your business logic

```
if ( $userCanInputMoreThanSixCharacter === true ) {
     $this->validator()->getField('ssc_roll')->setRule('maxlength', array(
        'rule' => array('maxlength',10),
        'required' => true
     ));
}
```

or you can remove the validation if the condition is true

```
if ( $userCanInputMoreThanSixCharacter === true ) {
     $this->validator()->remove('ssc_roll');
}
```